# issues implementing inter-thread communication using mailbox

Tags: c, multithreading

I am trying to implement inter-thread communication using a mailbox(i.e., a shared message buffer).

I have written the following functions for depositing a message into a mailbox and withdrawing from the mailbox, but I am sure I am missing something small (however, I can't figure out what). When I try to retrieve a message from the mailbox, the message length somehow is set to 0 when ideally it should be reading off the node in the buffer. My code for the mailbox functions, along with the test program and its expected output as well as the output I am getting are below:

```
void mbox_deposit(mbox *mb, char *msg, int len)
{
    struct msg *temp, *temp1;
    temp = GetNewMsgNode(len);

  //  temp = mb->msg_queue;

    sem_wait(mb->sem_mbox);
    // lock mailbox - critical section locked
    if(mb->msg_queue == NULL)
    {
        temp->message = msg;
        temp->length = len;
        temp->next = NULL;

        mb->msg_queue = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->message = msg;
        temp->length = len;
        temp->next = NULL;

        temp1 = mb->msg_queue;
        while(temp1->next != NULL)
            temp1 = temp1->next;

        temp1->next = temp;

    }
    // unlock mailbox - critical section unlocked
    sem_signal(mb->sem_mbox);
}


void mbox_withdraw(mbox *mb, char *msg, int *len)
{

  //  struct msg *temp;
   // temp = mb->msg_queue;

    sem_wait(mb->sem_mbox);
    // lock mailbox - critical section locked
    if(mb->msg_queue == NULL)
    {
        printf("No message to withdraw!");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        // withdraw first message from message queue
     //   temp = temp->next;

        len = &(mb->msg_queue->length);

        printf("%d", len);

        if(len != 0)
        {
            msg = mb->msg_queue->message;

            // make the msg_queue head point to the new first message in the queue after the first message has been removed
            if(mb->msg_queue->next != NULL)
                mb->msg_queue = mb->msg_queue->next;
        }

      //  free(temp);
    }
    // unlock mailbox - critical section unlocked
    sem_signal(mb->sem_mbox);

}
```

The test program with its expected output is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ud_thread.h"

mbox *mb;
char *msg[2] = {"hello world...", "bye, bye"};

void producer(int id) 
{
  int i;
  char mymsg[30];

  for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    sprintf(mymsg, "%s - tid %d", msg[i], id);
    printf("Producer (%d): [%s] [length=%d]\n", id, mymsg, strlen(mymsg));
    mbox_deposit(mb, mymsg, strlen(mymsg));
  }

  t_terminate();
}

void consumer(int id) 
{
  int i;
  int len;
  char mesg[1024];

  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    mbox_withdraw(mb, mesg, &len);
    printf("Message from mailbox: [%s]\n", mesg);
  }

  t_terminate();
}

int main(void) {

   t_init();

   mbox_create(&mb);
   t_create(producer, 1, 1);
   t_create(producer, 2, 1);
   t_create(consumer, 3, 1);  
   t_yield();
   mbox_destroy(&mb);

   t_shutdown();
   printf("Done with mailbox test...\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Expected Output:

```
Producer (1): [hello world... - tid 1] [length=22]
Producer (1): [bye, bye - tid 1] [length=16]
Producer (2): [hello world... - tid 2] [length=22]
Producer (2): [bye, bye - tid 2] [length=16]
Message from mailbox: [hello world... - tid 1]
Message from mailbox: [bye, bye - tid 1]
Message from mailbox: [hello world... - tid 2]
Message from mailbox: [bye, bye - tid 2]
Done with mailbox test...
```

However, What I end up getting with my mailbox functions is :

```
Producer (1): [hello world... - tid 1] [length=22]
Producer (1): [bye, bye - tid 1] [length=16]
Producer (2): [hello world... - tid 2] [length=22]
Producer (2): [bye, bye - tid 2] [length=16]
Message from mailbox: []
Message from mailbox: []
Message from mailbox: []
Message from mailbox: []
Done with mailbox test...
```

Any suggestions as to what I might be missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assignment has no effect for the caller:

```
void mbox_withdraw(mbox *mb, char *msg, int *len)
....
msg = mb->msg_queue->message;
```

You are simply changing your own copy of the pointer `msg`. This is a complicated example of a famous problem with a [C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html) (or maybe you are trying to copy strings the wrong way).

You likely want to do something like:

```
memcpy(msg, b->msg_queue->message, ...);
```

Or just use `strcpy` if you already trust the strings in the mailbox (which you probably do in a test program such as this).

---

EDIT

In your code `msg` is just a variable, a pointer. When you call the function, it points to the data in `char mesg[1024]`. But if you say `msg = mb->msg_queue->message` you make your variable `msg` **point to something else**. At the end of the function it doesn't matter any longer where `msg` points; all that matters is the effect on the caller.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the response! I see what you mean .... however, I thought mb->msg_queue->message would mean that I am referring to the message within the msg_queue node of type mailbox mb? So I am kinda confused when you say that I am changing my own copy of the pointer msg. msg is actually the message that needs to be withdrawn. Hope you can help me clarify this doubt better?

Comment: also, when I tried to implement the change you suggested, I am getting a seg fault! :(

Comment: @user2784743 I edited my answer. You must be copying the wrong size. Try using `strcpy` instead.